# union() method giving weird dataset values

Tags: apache-spark

I want to pile up the rows of many datasets into one. The datasets are stored in array and i use union() to add the rows of the previous dataset, given the array of datasets i described :

```
ArrayList<Dataset<Row>> dropped_added_cols_dataset_list = ...
```

i do it like so :

```
AD = dropped_added_cols_dataset_list.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < dropped_added_cols_dataset_list.size(); i++) {
              
    AD = AD.union(dropped_added_cols_dataset_list.get(i));
   }
```

But it seems as the final AD is showing weird values not related to those in each sub-dataset from the array described previously.
Anyone has an idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have the following *n* (here n == 3) number of Datasets as input stored in your `dropped_added_cols_dataset_list` list.

`df1`:

```
+---+----+----+
| _1|  _2|  _3|
+---+----+----+
|  0|cat1|30.9|
|  2|cat2|22.1|
|  0|cat3|19.6|
|  1|cat4| 1.3|
+---+----+----+
```

`df2`:

```
+---+----+----+
| _1|  _2|  _3|
+---+----+----+
|  1|cat5|28.5|
|  2|cat6|26.8|
|  1|cat7|12.6|
|  1|cat8| 5.3|
+---+----+----+
```

`df3`:

```
+---+-----+----+
| _1|   _2|  _3|
+---+-----+----+
|  1| cat9|39.6|
|  2|cat10|29.7|
|  0|cat11|27.9|
|  1|cat12| 9.8|
+---+-----+----+
```

We can apply the unions for all of them in the list without any user-specific loop, by using `reduce` (Java docs for Dataset's specified `reduce` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#reduce-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ReduceFunction-), working for the `ArrayList` through the `InterruptibleIterator` class that inherits `reduce` from the `scala.collection.TraversableOnce` interface as seen [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/InterruptibleIterator.html)) to merge the Datasets together in couples at a time.

```
// Java (`dropped_added_cols_dataset_list` is of type ArrayList)
list.reduce((ReduceFunction<Dataset>) (v1, v2) -> v1.union(v2));

// Scala (`dropped_added_cols_dataset_list` is of type List)
dropped_added_cols_dataset_list.reduce(_ union _)
```

The resulting Dataset will look like this:

```
+---+-----+----+
| _1|   _2|  _3|
+---+-----+----+
|  0| cat1|30.9|
|  2| cat2|22.1|
|  0| cat3|19.6|
|  1| cat4| 1.3|
|  1| cat5|28.5|
|  2| cat6|26.8|
|  1| cat7|12.6|
|  1| cat8| 5.3|
|  1| cat9|39.6|
|  2|cat10|29.7|
|  0|cat11|27.9|
|  1|cat12| 9.8|
+---+-----+----+
```

Of course, for the `union`s to be successful, you need to be extra careful that all of the Datasets stored in your list **have the exact same column schema**.

It also needs to be said that this solution's **performance is heavily dependent on the number of Datasets being merged**, so a relatively large number of `union`s can result to non-linear time complexity.

Comment: You have linked to `Dataset.reduce` but call `reduce` on an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Nice catch. I added a link to the `InterruptibleIterator` class documentation that is (probably) how `reduce` is supported in collections such as an `ArrayList`.